# MacOS 10.14: Disable headphone volume key repeat (prevent continous volume increase)

Tags: macos, headphones

(Macbook Pro late 2013, 10.14.6)

The behavior I want to prevent: If I hold a headphone volume control button pressed, the volume continues to increase (decrease) all the way up (down). I'd like to restrict this action to one increment by press, even if it's a continuous press. Any known way for this?

Or maybe a way to disable volume key repeat for the keyboard? I could imagine it would also affect the headphone buttons in a desired way.

Comment: Do you want to change the behaviour of the volume keys on the MBP keyboard, or of the volume keys on your headphone?

Comment: I mean the volume keys on my headphone. To prevent maxing the volume out if the button gets stuck - which occurs every now and then. By the way that doesn't happen on a machine with El Capitan.

Answer (score -1):

Key repeat can be turned off in the keyboard preference panel.  That's a global setting affecting all keys, if you want this behavior only on the volume controls then that's not going to help.